# Is it possible to read all pvc card data (a type of rfid card) in Android with NFC?

Tags: android, nfc, rfid

i want to read all stored rfid card in android with nfc but can't read anything except the ID card

this card has 1024 bytes mifare size and nfcA, mifare classic, NdefFormatable technologies

Comment: PVC card just means plastic card, so unless you know what protocol/RFID standard is being used, all anyone can do is refer you to the documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce#supported-protocols

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i have a student card. i can read id but i need to read all stored data in card. this card has 1024 bytes mifare size and nfcA, mifare classic, NdefFormatable technologies.